# Javadoc Hover suddenly broke in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse

I installed eclipse luna a week ago and worked every day with it until the javadoc broke yesterday.

When i hover on a class or method, the popup shows, with the right dimension apparently, but it's blank.

This problem happens for classes that i wrote, classes that come from maven dependencies and classes from the jdk (like String).

I restarted eclipse, the computer, and it still doesn't work.

I didn't notice anything i did diferently that could have caused this.

I looked at the build path and for each jar, there is the source path and the javadoc path.

The javadoc view is empty also.

I don't know what to do. I can't work without the javadoc hovers.

Edit : 
In the error view i saw that the first time i try to hover i get an Internal error on "org.eclipse.jdt.ui" :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: res
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementLinks$1.changing(JavaElementLinks.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE$7.handleEvent(IE.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventTable.sendEvent(OleEventTable.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.notifyListener(OleEventSink.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.Invoke(OleEventSink.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink.access$1(OleEventSink.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleEventSink$1.method6(OleEventSink.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.BrowserInformationControl.setVisible(BrowserInformationControl.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.showInformationControl(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.showInformationControl(TextViewerHoverManager.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.internalShowInformationControl(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractInformationControlManager.presentInformation(AbstractInformationControlManager.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.presentInformation(AbstractHoverInformationControlManager.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager.doPresentInformation(TextViewerHoverManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$5.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Edit 2 : it still doesn't work !

I uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled a fresh one, i wiped the workspace, there are no changes.

Comment: Try looking in the Error View for any messages (or the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory).

Comment: something is actually happening, i'll update the question. thanks :)

Comment: see following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26978109/346899

Comment: yeah it's a consequence of the workspace wipe, i just saw that, but it's not relevant, i still don't have the javadoc on hover. Sorry about that

Comment: Seems like problem with Internet Explorer - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=415834 . You should try to switch Eclipse to a different browser via `eclipse.ini` - http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault .

Comment: To be more clear - just add `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` at the end of your `eclipse.ini`. I am assuming that you have FireFox installed.

Comment: this is it, thanks ! write an answer so that i can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as the @Pavel Horal said
You should switch your browser to a different one , the default browser is IE by modifying the  eclipse.ini file [eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault)

or just add

> -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

at the end of your eclipse.ini file.

Or if you are more comfortable with UI interface of the eclipse you can use this help to change the default browser [HELP](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-42.htm).